# Geometry in QGIS 2.6

Tags: qgis, geometry, attribute-table

This might be a beginners question, but I could not find an answer on the internet.
I drew a couple of polygons in a vector layer and I am trying to get some basic geometric information into my attribute table (e. g. coordinates). I added a column with the value `§geometry`, which is as "Returns the geometry of the current feature". The column however is filled with NULL-values. I tried all the different field types, but the output always is NULL.

Can anybody tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert the geometry as wkt and also you have to select `Text, unlimited length (text)` as Output field type, because the output wkt is not an integer:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That worked, only my system crashed, because some of the polygons are pretty big :)

Comment: Last question: I have no option "Text, unlimited length" in my dropdown. I can only choose "Text (string)" with a maximum length of 255. Is this a special plugin or are you using PostGIS?

Comment: i use QGIS 2.8 ;) Probably this option does ot exist in QGIS 2.6. But the entry is limited by 255 characters. If you have a very complex polygon with a lot of points, probably 255 is not enough.

Comment: If your question is solved, please mark it as solved. Its the tick under the vote number ;) thank you

Comment: Thank you for your Help!
Next question (I'm not shure if I should open a new thread?: 
Are there other layertypes, which allow me to put in more then 255 characters? It would be good if I could put the whole polygons in one geometry. I need this to get values like cenroid etc. I have heard that PostGIS-Layers are capable of virtually unlimited entries, but I have never worked with PostGIS.

Comment: You could use spatialite if Postgis is too big for you. Spatialite has a BLOB geometry field type.